# Cannot find module 'fs-extra' in aws chime

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, aws-chime-sdk

I am trying to build a video conferencing application using AWS chime.
What I am trying to do is to follow the official documentation that is
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/business-productivity/building-a-meeting-application-using-the-amazon-chime-sdk/
but when I tried this I get an error after running this command in cloud9. I had replayed bucket name and stack name.
The error is

```
[Error code][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check this issue.
https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-chime-sdk-recording-demo/issues/21

Follow below operation then I was able to solve same problem.

```
pushd ~/environment/amazon-chime-sdk-js
npm install fs-extra
popd
```